# Can we multiply an electromagnetic field?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, reflection

[image: photomultiplier]

- can we multiply light by a sequence of reflections in a closed vessel?
- also, is light a part of EM wave?
- can we multiply the radio wave or EM wave from a transformer?

Comment: Is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photomultiplier) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

- We cannot multiply light by mere reflections, because the very definition of "reflection" means that the same light comes out. We *can* however multiply light by letting it pass through special materials which we "pumped" into a certain state, that's called [Laser.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser)

  And yes, a Laser design includes a sequence of reflections, but it is not the series of reflections that makes the amplification, but the passing through the amplification material.

  However the image you put in your question, showing a Photomultiplier, does *not* multiply light (despite its name). Instead, it multiplies electrons which are released from the material by the light.

  The basic idea of a photomultiplier is this: A photon kicks an electron out of the material. That electron is accelerated by an electric field, and then crashes against a material again, kicking *several* electrons out. Those are then again accelerated and hit against a target, where *each of them* kicks several other electrons out. So at each collision step, the number of electrons is multiplied, so that ultimately you get a measurable signal out of the single electron kicked out by a single photon.
- Light is not *part of* an electromagnetic wave, light *is an* electromagnetic wave.
- It is also possible to amplify radio waves. That's called a [Maser.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maser)